# how could explain for me how to save the preferred language enter by the user in a cookie with php

Tags: php, cookies, get, setcookie

```
<?php 
if (empty($_Get['language'])){
setcookie('langs',$_GET['language'], time()+365*24*3600 , null, null,false,true);
echo $_COOKIE['langs'];}
?>

<!doctype>
<html>
   <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title> application_formulaire </title>
   </head>

    <body>
    <form methode="GET"  >
         <input type = "text" name = "language" />
         <input type="submit" value="save" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

good evening, I'm still a beginner in php .the exercise idea in the first place was that save the preferred language enter by the user in a cookie. I realized this code but I can not understand why it worked (notament in 2nd line)
normally language field (input) must be **filled in** and this data is saved as a cookie this matches the condition if (isset($_Get['language']))

```
if (isset($_Get['language']))
```

but it doesn't work of the contrary

```
(empty($_Get['language']))
```

it workss but still appears illogic for me .

Comment: Typo #1 `$_Get['language']`... Should be `$_GET['language']` - #2 `<form methode="GET"  >` should be `<form method="GET"  >`.

Comment: thank you , i correct them  but still having the same problem, also if my code seem not correct and any one has a better solution please show it to me and thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the form **is not** empty you want to create a cookie with the users information. So firstly,

- if(empty($_Get['language'])) should be changed to
- if(**!**empty($_**GET**['language'])){ create cookie here}

Secondly I don't see anything wrong with the cookie you create.

- setcookie('langs',$_GET['language'], time()+365*24*3600 , null, null, false, true);

In the first example I added the logical **!** Not operator. Meaning if the user input **IS NOT** empty create a cookie containing the data from user submission.